# Thread switching by ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

Does the following test pass always or not? If not, what is the condition?

```
    [Test]
    public async Task Test()
    {
        var before = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

        var after = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        Assert.AreNotEqual(before, after);
    }
```

Comment: Why use this code at all? Why not `public async Task Test()`? The question isn't very usefull. `ConfigureAwait()` means execution doesn't need to return to the original *synchronization context*. That doesn't mean thread, especially in console and ASP.NET applications. The *original* thread is released as soon as an async operation starts anyway so it may be availalbe to handle the continuation after `await`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it doesn't matter, but I have changed as you asked.

Comment: Once you're using `Task`s, worrying about *threads* is to entirely miss the point of having moved to a higher level abstraction.

Comment: To add to @Damien_The_Unbeliever comment. Don't use `ManagedThreadId` or `[ThreadStatic]` attribute when you are using asynchronous code. If you do you are asking for trouble.

Comment: It is not valid.  What you overlook is the possibility of the code before the await being executed by a threadpool thread.  Which completed and then got reused to execute the continuation.  Just don't test ConfigureAwait(), it does not have a bug.

Comment: @HansPassant First of all, thank you for you answer. I don't suppose that the test presents a "bug" or a "wrong behavior of ConfigureAwait". No, I just asked about threads before and after await. May be it's not very useful and you are right, but let's suppose it's more academic interest rather than production one.